# Как удалить из char массива элементы?

Tags: java

Стоит задача: проверить на коррекцию файл со скобками.

Вот что написал:

```
public class BracketsValid {
void bracketsValid() throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите путь: ");
    String path = in.nextLine(); //получаем путь и затем его просваиваем переменной file

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(path));
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);

    String lines = String.valueOf(fr);
    int l = lines.length();
    System.out.println(l);

    char[] current = new char[l];



    for (int i = 0; fis.available() > 0; i++) {
        current[i] = (char) fis.read();
    }

    String str = String.valueOf(current);
    String ss = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (current[i] == '(' || current[i] == '{' || current[i] == '[' || current[i] == ')' || current[i] == '}' || current[i] == ']')
            ss += current[i];
        System.out.println(ss);
    }

    current = ss.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < ss.length() - 1; i++) {
        if ((current[i] == '(' && current[i + 1] == ')') || (current[i] == '[' && current[i + 1] == ']') || (current[i] == '{' && current[i + 1] == '}')) {


            i = -1;
        }
    }

    if(ss.length() == 1)
        System.out.println(str + "   Скобки расставлены правильно");
    else
        System.out.println(str + "   Скобки расставлены неправильно");
}
```

}

Застрял в конце, я нашёл корректные скобки, хочу их удалить, но не знаю как, чтобы цикл дальше работал. Подскажите, как можно решить ситуацию?

Comment: Копировать в новый массив с пропуском ненужного.

Answer (score 2):

1. В начале вы инициализируете массив `current` некоторым количеством `l` пустых элементов. Далее в цикле ищите в нем скобки. Но символы вы в массив не записали. Более того, в вашем случае нет смысла заводить этот массив. Итерируйтесь сразу по строке `lines`. Доступ к элементу строки осуществляется через метод `lines.charAt(i)`.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < lines.length(); i++) {
       final char c = lines.charAt(i);
       if (c == '(' || c == '{' || c == '[' || c == ')' || c == '}' || c == ']')
           ss += c;
       System.out.println(ss);
   }
   ```

Также и в цикле ниже не нужно использовать массив. Используйте строки напрямую. Также не ясен смысл переменной `str`.

2. `String` в Java - неизменяемый класс. Если вам нужно менять строку, то не нужно ее каждый раз перезаписывать. Верным решением будет использовать `StringBuilder` (или `StringBuffer` для многопоточного). Этот класс лучше всего подойдет, чтобы "копировать с пропуском ненужного" (как написала @HasmikGaryaka).
3. Ваше условие не учитывает вложенность. Подумайте, что будет со строкой вида `[текст(текст)текст]`.
4. Для поиска/проверки парных скобок, вообще говоря, достаточно написать регулярное выражение и получится красивое решение в несколько строк.

Comment: Извиняюсь за долгий ответ. Хорошо, когда буду о проекта, проверю ваши слова, спасибо за ответ))